# How to run <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>

Tags: php, apache, lamp

After copying and pasting

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

Into a file named `index.php` and navigating to my ip the only output is `www-data`.

Is this the Apache process owner?

Is there a way to run this from the terminal for a more finite output?

Comment: What are you expecting to get as a result?

Comment: not sure but i was finally able to write image data to a folder using php after using the `www-data` value when setting permissions

Comment: Use system() function. Without echo.

Answer (score 2):

As the manual said, `whoami` **Print the user name associated with the current effective user ID**. In other words, it displays the name of the currently logged-in user.
So your server Apache is run under `www-data` username.